# Efficient way to create an array that is a sequence of variable length ranges in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have an array

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([5,7,2])
```

I want to create an array that contains a sequence of ranges stacked together with the 
length of each range given by x:

```
y=np.hstack([np.arange(1,n+1) for n in x])
```

Is there some way to do this without the speed penalty of a list comprehension or looping. (x could be a very large array)

The result should be

```
y == np.array([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2])
```

Comment: do you mean an array with a different number of rows/cols for each col/row?

Comment: Can you show an example of the result you are looking for? The current code for `y` doesnt work because elements of the numpy array will be different lengths.

Comment: The result should be an array. Sorry for the errors in the original code! Should be fixed now

Comment: What is the a maximum length of `x` and maximum of `x`? Also is `x` unique?

Comment: If you are planning on iterating over this, maybe turn it into a generator so you don't have to make it all at once and store it in memory.  It may not be much faster, but it won't happen all at once.

Comment: @Ophion length of x could be 1,000,000 or more rows and the maximum x around 20. x values are not unique. (Memory is not the most important issue, but speed is).

Answer (score 5):

You could use accumulation:

```
def my_sequences(x):
    x = x[x != 0] # you can skip this if you do not have 0s in x.

    # Create result array, filled with ones:
    y = np.cumsum(x, dtype=np.intp)
    a = np.ones(y[-1], dtype=np.intp)

    # Set all beginnings to - previous length:
    a[y[:-1]] -= x[:-1]

    # and just add it all up (btw. np.add.accumulate is equivalent):
    return np.cumsum(a, out=a) # here, in-place should be safe.
```

(One word of caution: If you result array would be larger then the possible size `np.iinfo(np.intp).max` this might with some bad luck return wrong results instead of erroring out cleanly...)

And because everyone always wants timings (compared to Ophion's) method:

```
In [11]: x = np.random.randint(0, 20, 1000000)

In [12]: %timeit ua,uind=np.unique(x,return_inverse=True);a=[np.arange(1,k+1) for k in ua];np.concatenate(np.take(a,uind))
1 loops, best of 3: 753 ms per loop

In [13]: %timeit my_sequences(x)
1 loops, best of 3: 191 ms per loop
```

of course the `my_sequences` function will not ill-perform when the values of `x` get large.

Comment: Really demonstrates how slow `concatenate` is. When I was timing my data it was the majority of the final codes time. +1!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the sort of numpy voodoo I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 4):

First idea; prevent multiple calls to `np.arange` and `concatenate` should be much faster then `hstack`:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([5,7,2])

>>>a=np.arange(1,x.max()+1)
>>> np.hstack([a[:k] for k in x])
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2])

>>> np.concatenate([a[:k] for k in x])
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2])
```

If there are many nonunique values this seems more efficient:

```
>>>ua,uind=np.unique(x,return_inverse=True)
>>>a=[np.arange(1,k+1) for k in ua]
>>>np.concatenate(np.take(a,uind))

array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2])
```

Some timings for your case:

```
x=np.random.randint(0,20,1000000)
```

Original code

```
#Using hstack
%timeit np.hstack([np.arange(1,n+1) for n in x])
1 loops, best of 3: 7.46 s per loop

#Using concatenate
%timeit np.concatenate([np.arange(1,n+1) for n in x])
1 loops, best of 3: 5.27 s per loop
```

First code:

```
#Using hstack
%timeit a=np.arange(1,x.max()+1);np.hstack([a[:k] for k in x])
1 loops, best of 3: 3.03 s per loop

#Using concatenate
%timeit a=np.arange(1,x.max()+1);np.concatenate([a[:k] for k in x])
10 loops, best of 3: 998 ms per loop
```

Second code:

```
%timeit ua,uind=np.unique(x,return_inverse=True);a=[np.arange(1,k+1) for k in ua];np.concatenate(np.take(a,uind))
10 loops, best of 3: 522 ms per loop
```

Looks like we gain a 14x speedup with the final code.

Small sanity check:

```
ua,uind=np.unique(x,return_inverse=True)
a=[np.arange(1,k+1) for k in ua]
out=np.concatenate(np.take(a,uind))

>>>out.shape
(9498409,)

>>>np.sum(x)
9498409
```

Comment: Both answers look good. I think your second answer works for my use case of x with large length, but small maximum value.